# Have a control selected in a loaded view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nswindowcontroller, nsviewcontroller

I have a question about using NSViewController and switching between views. I have a Cocoa application where I have a window. The idea with the window is that it will display a number of views one by one where each view is stored in a separate XIB file. Each view has a corresponding NSViewController. I have made a minimal example of what I'm doing where only the first view is loaded.

```
@interface MyWindowController : NSWindowController {
    NSViewController *currentViewController;
}
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSView *targetView;
@end

@implementation MyWindowController

@synthesize targetView;

- (id)init
{
    return [super initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindow"];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [currentViewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];

    currentViewController = [[NSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil];
    [self.targetView addSubview:currentViewController.view];
    [currentViewController.view setFrame:targetView.bounds];
}

@end
```

When the window is loaded the view from FirstView.xib is also loaded and the view is displayed in the window. In this case the loaded view only has a text field and I would like the text field to be highlighted so that input can be written to it directly without the user having to click on it but I can't figure out how to do that. Is it possible to have the text field selected when the view is loaded?

After reading the documentation I have found that I probably want to set the window's initialFirstResponder to the text field, but I can't find how to do that when the text field is in a different XIB file than the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you add/replace a subview and want it to be the first responder, have your window controller make the view the first responder of the window managed by the window controller:

```
[[self window] makeFirstResponder:currentViewController.view];
```

You’ll want to do this in both `-windowDidLoad` and whichever other methods add/replace subviews.

Comment: For the record by setting not just the view but its netKeyView to become the first responder and set the corresponding outlet in IB to the text field I could have the text field selected after the view was loaded. Otherwise the view itself became the first responder the the text field would be selected when tab was pressed.

Comment: @Brian True; that depends on what the subview actually is.